# Series Expansion $\frac{1}{1-x}\log\frac{1}{1-x}=\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\cdots+\frac{1}{n}\right)x^n$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

How do I prove that, if $|x|<1$, then $$\frac{1}{1-x}\log\frac{1}{1-x}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+...+\frac{1}{n}\right)x^n$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\frac1{1-x}\log\frac1{1-x}=\sum_{i\geqslant0}x^i\cdot\sum_{k\geqslant1}\frac{x^k}k=\sum_{i\geqslant0,k\geqslant1}\frac{x^{k+i}}k=\sum_{n\geqslant1}\ldots x^n$$

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**

Think to the Cauchy product
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n \sum_{n=0}^\infty b_n=\sum_{n=0}^\infty c_n$$
where
$$c_n=\sum_{k=0}^n a_kb_{n-k}$$